# Cómo puedo buscar y reemplazar en un List<String[]>

Tags: java, lista, java-8, lambda, java-stream

tengo dos Listas de tipo:

```
    List<String[]> globallist= new ArrayList<>();
    List<String[]> list1= new ArrayList<>();
    List<String[]> list2= new ArrayList<>();
```

Su contenido es el siguiente:

```
globallist: [[1,A,null,null, null],[2,B,null,null, null],[3,C,null,null, null],[4,C,null,null, null]]
list1: [[1,A,23,24, 25],[2,B,34,35, 35],[3,C,1,53, 5]]
list2: [[4,C,23,24, 25],[2,B,39,5, 32]]
```

Me gustaría poder llenar la lista, si la posición de la lista 1 [0] y[1] son iguales a la lista global, agregar el elemento (por ejemplo) [2] en la posición [2] de la lista global:

Ejemplo
pseudocodigo:

```
if list1 [0] = globalList [0] %% list1 [1] = globalList [1] 
then globalList set (globalList [0],list1 [2])
```

Resultado

```
 globallist: [[1,A,23,null, null],[2,B,34,null, null],[3,C,1,null, null],[4,C,null,null, null]]
```

Se puede sacar con streams? lambdas? estoy ocupando java 8

Answer (score 0):

Pues básicamente necesitas recorrer la lista global e ir comparando. Cuando se cumpla el requisito seteas el valor de la lista1 a la global.

PD: No lo hice con lambdas por que al menos deberías tratar de hacer algún ejemplo mínimo verificable para comenzar por allí.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Alvarez
 */
public class main {

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] globall = {"1", "A", null, null};
        String[] global2 = {"2", "B", null, null};
        String[] global3 = {"3", "C", null, null};

        String[] lista1 = {"1", "A", "24", "25"};
        String[] lista2 = {"2", "B", "35", "35"};
        String[] lista3 = {"3", "C", "1", "5"};

        List<String[]> globalList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String[]> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String[]> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        globalList.add(globall);
        globalList.add(global2);
        globalList.add(global3);

        list1.add(lista1);
        list1.add(lista2);
        list1.add(lista3);

        for (int i = 0; i < globalList.size(); i++) {
            if (globalList.get(i)[0].equals(list1.get(i)[0]) && globalList.get(i)[1].equals(list1.get(i)[1])) {
                globalList.get(i)[2] = list1.get(i)[2];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < globalList.size(); i++) {
            System.err.println(globalList.get(i)[2]);

        }

    }
}
```

Output de listaGlobal:

24
35
1